# Mapview Plotting annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I want to add more that 200 mkannotaion on map. I am able to implement 200 annotation but while I am trying to implement more. Application is getting terminated by iphone os showing memory problem. Is there any solution for it

Comment: Specify Termination reason?

Comment: memory problem, iphone os can not assign memory for 600 annotation implementation

Comment: You can use clustering to present markers

Comment: @Shwetaparjane i think joy is right, read [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/marker-clustering). It makes app lightweighted and it is easy to use also. There is no reason to make app heavy, may be further you have touch issue or may be your app have bad performance issue.